# Error al momento de realizar un test a un componente de react con jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pruebas-unitarias, babeljs, jestjs

he intentado realizar una prueba unitaria a un código

```
export function getSaludo(nombre) {
    return 'Hola ' + nombre;
}

console.log( `Este es un texto: ${ getSaludo( nombre ) }  ` );
```

Obviamente el codigo me deberia dar un error pero cuando lo pruebo con npm jest despues de instalar jest me arroja este error

FAIL  tests/base-pruebas/02-template-string.test.js
● Test suite failed to run

```
You appear to be using a native ECMAScript module configuration file, which is only supported when running Babel asynchronously.

  at loadCodeDefault (node_modules/@babel/core/src/config/files/module-types.ts:52:9)
      at loadCodeDefault.next (<anonymous>)
  at readConfigCode (node_modules/@babel/core/src/config/files/configuration.ts:75:37)
      at readConfigCode.next (<anonymous>)
  at Function.<anonymous> (node_modules/@babel/core/src/gensync-utils/async.ts:10:3)
  at evaluateSync (node_modules/gensync/index.js:251:28)
  at Function.sync (node_modules/gensync/index.js:89:14)
  at sync (node_modules/@babel/core/src/gensync-utils/async.ts:83:25)
  at sync (node_modules/gensync/index.js:182:19)
  at onFirstPause (node_modules/gensync/index.js:210:24)
  at cachedFunction (node_modules/@babel/core/src/config/caching.ts:131:34)
      at cachedFunction.next (<anonymous>)
  at evaluateSync (node_modules/gensync/index.js:251:28)
  at node_modules/gensync/index.js:31:34
      at Array.map (<anonymous>)
  at Function.sync (node_modules/gensync/index.js:31:22)
  at Function.all (node_modules/gensync/index.js:210:24)
  at all (node_modules/@babel/core/src/config/files/configuration.ts:264:34)
      at loadOneConfig.next (<anonymous>)
  at buildRootChain (node_modules/@babel/core/src/config/config-chain.ts:171:39)
      at buildRootChain.next (<anonymous>)
  at loadPrivatePartialConfig (node_modules/@babel/core/src/config/partial.ts:110:44)
      at loadPrivatePartialConfig.next (<anonymous>)
  at Function.loadPrivatePartialConfig (node_modules/@babel/core/src/config/partial.ts:173:12)
  at evaluateSync (node_modules/gensync/index.js:251:28)
  at Function.sync (node_modules/gensync/index.js:89:14)
  at sync (node_modules/@babel/core/src/config/index.ts:58:21)
  at ScriptTransformer._getCacheKey (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:228:41)
  at ScriptTransformer._getFileCachePath (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:289:27)
  at ScriptTransformer.transformSource (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:522:32)
  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:671:40)
  at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:723:19)
```

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.46 s
Ran all test suites.

Ya tengo configurado babel según la documentación de jest  y me arroja ese error.

Revisando la documentación de babel he insertado en el archivo config de babel API para trabajar de manera asincrona, código de transformación y le he cambiado la extensión a babel.config.cjs y nada de esto me ha funcionado.

Agradecería mucho si alguien me puede ayudar saludos